# React redux-form get value of field to set other field

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

How can I get the value of one field so that onChange I can set the value of a different field with redux-form in react?

```
<Field
    fullWidth
    name="FieldName"
    component={renderTextField}
    label="FieldLabel"
    onChange={this.props.change('FieldNameAlt', 9999)}
/>
```

Instead of 9999, say I wanted it to be the value of `FieldName*2`.  How should I get the value of `FieldName` to set the value of `FieldNameAlt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can get the value of the changed field by simply using the `event` passed to the `onChange`:

```
onChange={e => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    this.props.change('FieldNameAlt', val)
}};
```

Comment: awesome, glad to help